# Playframework extension/overriding points

Tags: playframework

I wanna know how PlayFramework is extensible.

The case i have in mind is to override Mailer component: in some cases it could be interesting to override it to test application in "dev" mode and also to be sure the component implementation used sends mail to our developper mail adress (even if the mail is functionally sent to a "real" user).
It could be also used to "forward" mail to a platform (free or charges) dedicated to send mail (in case webhosting provides limited mail send functions...).

Please let me know if see how whe can override the Mailer component (without to hack playframework core source code but by adding modules or plugins)

Best regards,
Loïc

Answer (score 2):

The `Mail` component is a class in a library, rather than a plugin. What you would need to do to fulfill your use-case would be to create your own, or extend the `play.libs.Mail` class, and when sending a mail message, use your own class rather than the shipped Play class.

You can see the class here - https://github.com/playframework/play/blob/master/framework/src/play/libs/Mail.java

Comment: I understand your solution but the issue is that i will have to change all calls to the Mail class by call to my implementation...

Comment: are theses calls you have already implemented, core play, or other modules?

Comment: I mean there are a lot of modules (not only in my app) using that Mailer component. The goal would be to replace the Mailer implementation by one other (by configuration) without to affect modules and applications using it. You see my point?

Comment: yes, unfortunately I don't see this being possible as it is direct class access, and not through a factory. Therefore a change of source is likely required.

Comment: Ok anyway thank you for your answer i ll maybe propose to embed that enhancement in a new Play version

Answer (score 0):

For development Play has a mock mailer (you set it in your application.conf). The mock mailer will simply print the contents of the mail to the shell, Eclipse console etc.

For production the easiest way is probably to setup your host to use something like SSMTP or Nullmailer, for example you can use a GMail account and send email uses Google's SMTP servers if you want a cheap setup. The nice thing with using SSMTP / Nullmailer is that Play is completely unaware of you mail configuration and you are free to change it whenever you want without doing any code changes.

Comment: Your proposal could cover my need. I ll investigate and let you know if it is ok. Thanks.